# Where does complex number multiplication (as vectors, not referencing $i$) come from?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

It is [specified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) as this:

$$(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc).\,$$

I don't see anywhere where the decision to have `-` these components $ac-bd$ and `+` these components $ad+bc$ was made. Or why it is like this. Wondering if one could explain why it's like this, without using or referencing $i$ or $\sqrt{-1}$, just using the idea of complex numbers as an ordered pair of reals.

Comment: Hm. If we treat $(a,b)$ as a vector of two elements (and of course the same for $(c,d)$), the left component of the multiplication looks something like the dot product, but with a subtraction instead. I wonder what that could mean. And if we were to concatenate the two into a $2 \times 2$ matrix columnwise like so:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\ 
b & d
\end{bmatrix}$$

then the right component of the multiplication is the determinant of this matrix but with addition in lieu of subtraction.

Comment: Not sure if these mean anything because they're *similar* but not quite on the mark, but hopefully it means something. EDIT: Never mind, James posted an answer that filled in the details I was missing.

Comment: "an ordered pair of vectors": you probably mean *reals*.

Comment: "Could someone explain why it is like this, without using or referencing the reason why it is like this?" ???

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am new to this so how would I know that that is the reason why it's like this lol.

Comment: I mention not using $i$ because that is what is done [here](http://www.workinginuncertainty.co.uk/imaginary.pdf).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't think ihat is the best choice of duplicate for this sort of question so I have voted to reopen

Comment: @BillDubuque: The two questions seem to be asking fairly exactly the same. What makes you think they're not duplicates?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  There are *many* possible ways to answer this question, and the linked dupe has only one answer - which is far from representing all of the possible viewpoints. I think is is wrong to close with such a dupe target (even more so when it is a gold-badge closure with your own unique answer, when there are many possible answers)

Comment: @BillDubuque: The previous instance of the question is not closed -- it is free for anyone to post more answers to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from the fact that every complex number $z=a+ib$ corresponds to a matrix of the form $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}.$$ Now take another matrix of this form, say $$B=\begin{pmatrix}c & -d \\ d & c\end{pmatrix}.$$ The product $$AB=\begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c & -d \\ d & c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ac-bd & -(ad+bc) \\ (ad+bc) & ac-bd\end{pmatrix}.$$ You can again read of real and imaginary part of the product from this. If you are interested in why complex numbers correspond to such matrices, I can write a few lines about this fact here or you spend some minutes searching for it on the internet.

Comment: Why did this answer get a downvote? If you are nor satisfied, drop a comment to let me know what is wrong with it..

Comment: Not me, I think this is helpful. Would be nice to include why matrices are related, though I have seen it mentioned and will look it up further. Having it in one place is nice.

Comment: This answer explains nothing. It just recasts the question in terms of matrices, and the "arbitrariness" of the definition remains.

Comment: @user10869858 There is a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028371/complex-number-isomorphic-to-certain-2-times-2-matrices but I am willing to write a few lines about polar coordinates and the correspondence to matrices of this type, if you find nothing adequate

Comment: @YvesDaoust that's a good point, though knowing it's related to matrices at least adds some info to the mix.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't agree. I think it shows that the product comes from a matrix product and that is the reason to define it the way one does define it..

Comment: @James: nonsense. In what way does that justify the $-$ and $+$ signs ? Read the question.

Comment: This plus and minus for real numbers. And as far as I read the question, it is asked why complex multiplication is defined the way it is. Because at first it looks very awkward. Thus understanding that it comes from matrix multiplication and is thus induced from something *well-known* is something that I consider helpful and also to answer why the definition is as it is.

Comment: The fact that you have a multiplication on $\mathbb R^2$ implies that any $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ gives rise to a linear map $L_{(a,b)}:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $L_{(a,b)}(c,d)=(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc).$

Making some plausible assumption, namely that $L_{(1,0)}$ is the identity matrix and that $L_{(0,1)}$ is given by rotation by $\pi/2$, and using the fact that $L_{(a,b)}(c,d)=L_{(c,d)}(a,b)$ for any $(a,b),(c,d)\in\mathbb R^2$, it is easy to check that the representing matrix of $L_{(a,b)}$ is the one appearing in James's answer.

Comment: If anyone has a better answer, feel free and I will reevaluate, but for now this answers most of what I was looking for. Now I at least know it's based on matrix multiplication, would be nice to know why that was chosen as the multiplication method, but this is enough for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unreasonable, since it is *because* someone (Hamilton, in this case) was trying to formalize the complex numbers, as things of the form $a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $i^2=1$, that that definition was obtained.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote. This *is* an excellent answer. The abstract formalism $(a,b)$ was derived from this.

Comment: This answer doesn't say anything to me, and it is a bit condescending.

Comment: @user10869858: not condescending at all. Just telling you the truth. Complex multiplication was *not* defined without referring to $i$.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense. But it seems the [Cayley Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) doesn't reference $i$, maybe though in textbooks it does since it does ref complex numbers which are (typically I guess) defined by $i$.

Comment: **No** construction of $\mathbb C$ makes reference to $i$. The idea of constructing the complex numbers is that $i$ makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the geometric interpretation of the complex numbers, $(a,b)$ is a point in the plane, the components of which are abscissa and ordinate.

Complex numbers are seen, in polar form, as a vector length and vector angle. The complex multiplication by $(0,1)$ is defined to be a rotation by a right angle. More generally, multiplication by a complex can be seen as the application of a similarity transform, i.e. the combination of a scaling and a rotation.

Now if you look at the product of two complex numbers as the combination of two similarity transforms, considering the rotation only, you need to enforce

$$(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)(\cos\beta,\sin\beta)=(\cos(\alpha+\beta),\sin(\alpha+\beta)),$$ as the combination of two rotations is a single rotation by the sum of the angles.

And recall,

$$(\cos(\alpha+\beta),\sin(\alpha+\beta))=(\cos\alpha\cos\beta\color{red}-\sin\alpha\sin\beta,\sin\alpha\cos\beta\color{red}+\cos\alpha\sin\beta).$$

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the element-wise addition and the multiplication defined above satisfies the field axioms (you can check it).

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't really enlighten anyone as to the inspiration underlying this definition. It forms a field with this definition, but I feel like OP is reaching more towards an idea of "why *this* definition?"

Comment: @EeveeTrainer The inspiration is that we want to make a function $*$, which will make $(\mathbb{R}^2, +, *)$ a field.

Comment: I get that, but surely there are all sorts of definitions which would achieve that - which begs the question, why this particular one?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I haven't seen any other $*$ operation which would make a field with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and element-wise addition. Would you show me a different one?

Comment: I'll admit that I don't know of one off-hand, but we don't have the assurance that the multiplication is *unique*, either, so I would think that - even if I can't come up with one at this moment - there's at least a possibility another exists. You know what I mean?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You were right, we can make a lot of different field. An easy example that came in my mind is just to swap the "meanings" of the coordinates.I think we can restrict the possibilities with demanding $(a,0)*(b,0)=(a*b,0)$, but it won't solve every problem, right?